# Add to favourites functionality using MVVM Best Practice

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am working with MVVM architecture and trying to use best practices in documentation.
Let me explain what I have done and what is my problem.

I have a fragment and a parent fragment. When user enters a string to searchview which is in parent fragment, I collect the data and fetch the list to recyclerview.
I have a list adapter which takes care of favourite button for each elements in recyclerview. And I implemented a callback to listadapter:

```
val onFavouriteChanged: (id, isFavourited) -> Unit
```

In my viewmodel, I have MutableStateFlow to update and collect UI data. Something like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SearchViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) :
    ViewModel() {
    private var _ViewState =
        MutableStateFlow(ViewState(onFavouriteChanged = { Id, isFavorite ->
            viewModelScope.launch {
                if (isFavorite) {
                    repository.unmarkAsFavorite(Id)
                } else {
                    repository.markAsFavorite(Id)
                }
                searchContent(ViewState.value.searchText)
            }
        }))
        val ViewState: StateFlow<ViewState> = _ViewState
...
```

When user clicked a favourite button, I immediately let backend to know user is favourited that item. Then I refetch the data from callback function using same query text:

```
searchContent(ViewState.value.searchText)
```

In my viewmodel i check the new updated data, if user favourited item i change the color of favourite button. It works pretty good.

But the problem is that, when user clicked a favourite button it takes time to update backend, then refetching updated data. So there is a pretty good delay since user clicked the button and saw the button's color change.

My question is, what and how is the best practice to bypass that delay. Should I update the favourited ui state before I even inform the backend? If so where and which layer should i do that? Is it possible to update a list's one item's favourited state in viewmodel?

This is my UIState

```
data class ViewState(
    val list: List<WallItemCampaignResponse> = listOf(),
    val onFavouriteChanged: (Long, Boolean) -> Unit,
    var searchText: String = ""
)
```

Comment: Since you haven't posted how your repository implementation, I can suggest updating the `View` first (`searchContent`) as the network can block the thread (delay) & update the backend after that like you are already doing in the `viewModelScope.launch`.

Comment: If i call searchContent first, then new data from backend wont include new favourite data.

Comment: My bad, I thought `searchContent` was updating the `View`. In that case, you change the View's background colour first & perform network tasks post that.

Comment: I think i can change the color in the adapter but my lead says its not best practice to change the data in adapter so i am confused